# How to add backspace in a Linux terminal command?

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I need to execute the following command to ssh into a device on a network whose credentials have been saved.

```
ans = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','sshpass','-p',iplist[index][3],'ssh',iplist[index][2],'@',iplist[index][2]])
```

This is executed on Ubuntu in a Python environment. 
I want to actually execute-

```
sudo sshpass -p password username@hostname
```

It is quite possible that there is a space before and afer '@'.
How do I eliminate that?

Comment: It's not so much that there's a space, but that they're explicitly passed as two separate arguments: The argument list on UNIX (and so across all programming languages on that OS) is really a list of separate C strings; when you pass one string with spaces to the shell, the shell splits it up into individual strings before starting the program being called. Passing an array to `subprocess.Popen()`, you're forming that list yourself rather than generating a string and letting it be split elsewhere -- giving you more control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenate them to one argument

```
ans = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'sshpass', '-p', iplist[index][3], 'ssh', iplist[index][2] + '@' + iplist[index][2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to merge `iplist[index][2],'@',iplist[index][2]` into a **single** item in the list:

```
ans = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','sshpass','-p', iplist[index][3],'ssh','{}@{}'.format(iplist[index][2], iplist[index][2])])
```